# Is there any way to use Vuex with inline-templates?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

How my store can look like if my templates look like.

Template in php:

```
<?php foreach($todos as $todo) : ?>
   <todo inline-template>
       <div>
           <div><?php echo $todo->name ?></div>
           <input type="checkobox" @click="toggle">
       </div>
   </todo>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Component:

```
<script>   
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                finished: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggle() {
                this.finished = !this.finished;
            },
        }
    };
</script>
```

For instance, I want to show some message if a user has more than 5 finished todos. How can I do this?
How can I match a component state that some the todos are marked finished with the state in the store?

And I want to use Vuex but I have many vue instances (not SPA). And the idea to share one state between all of them to have one source of truth.

Comment: Can you show us an MCVE? From here it's rather difficult to guess/deduce what you're really asking about.

Comment: @Terry I've updated my question. Hope it's more clear now. Thanks.